# How was the Ferris wheel scene shot in Jackass 3.5?

Tags: film-techniques, jackass

In [*Jackass 3.5* (2011)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1753968/), there is a scene where a ball exactly hit someone in the groin (*ouch!*) even though it was thrown from a Ferris wheel.

[image]

[image]

How was this scene shot? How did the Jackass team achieve such an accurate shot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They took a long time and many attempts.

We only see the successful version.

Transcript of Johnny Knoxville on Twitter ([**Source**](http://www.dickhouse.tv/dickhouse/2011/06/johnny-knoxville-conquers-the-interweb.html))

> incredible nut shots bit took more time to shoot than any five bits we have ever done.
>
> i think the 4th street bridge shot took 3 days to get. and the **ferris wheel shot took two days** to get.